# MERGE statement Linked Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Trying to use the `MERGE` statement in SQL Server and get the following error. Not sure what I'm overlooking here. The insert and values count are the same.

> There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.

Statement below

```
MERGE EHRCLSQL01.NOCAdmin.dbo.ViewOnlyTracking AS vot
USING 
   (SELECT 
       @Database AS [Database], 
       'Copy' AS Mode, 
       CASE WHEN @Passed = 0 THEN 'Failed' ELSE 'Success' END AS [Status], 
       @Duration AS Duration, 
       GETDATE() AS DateTimestamp, 
       GETDATE() AS LastSuccessDateTimestamp) AS s ON vot.[Database] = s.[Database]
                                                      AND vot.Mode = s.Mode
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE 
      SET           
        vot.[Status] = s.[Status]
        , vot.Duration = s.Duration
        , vot.DateTimestamp = s.DateTimestamp
        , vot.LastSuccessDateTimestamp = s.LastSuccessDateTimestamp

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ([Database], [Mode], [Status], [Duration], [DateTimestamp], [LastSuccessDateTimestamp])
    VALUES (s.[Database], s.Mode, s.[Status], s.Duration, s.DateTimestamp, NULL);
```

**Update**:

Fixed the closing ]. Now I get the following

> The target of a MERGE statement cannot be a remote table, a remote view, or a view over remote tables.

Since I'm using data from the target server and attempting to update the linked server how can I perform this?

Comment: s.[Database  doesn't have the closing ]

Comment: haha wow >.> thanks updating and posting the new error

Comment: The new error seems pretty clear - you cannot use a MERGE statement to update a remote table.  You'll need to use separate `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements.  Or look at ETL tools like SSIS.

Comment: Not 100% sure here, but can you run the merge on the remote and pull the data from the server you are currently running on instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [EXECUTE AT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) to make the merge statement happen on the remote server side.

Put your query in a variable, use ? as placeholder for the parameters and then execute.

Something like this could work for you.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
MERGE NOCAdmin.dbo.ViewOnlyTracking AS vot
    USING (SELECT ? AS [Database], ''Copy'' AS Mode, CASE WHEN ? = 0 THEN ''Failed'' ELSE ''Success'' END AS [Status], ? AS Duration, GETDATE() AS DateTimestamp, GETDATE() AS LastSuccessDateTimestamp) AS s
        ON vot.[Database] = s.[Database]
            AND vot.Mode = s.Mode
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET          
                vot.[Status] = s.[Status]
                , vot.Duration = s.Duration
                , vot.DateTimestamp = s.DateTimestamp
                , vot.LastSuccessDateTimestamp = s.LastSuccessDateTimestamp

        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT ([Database], [Mode], [Status], [Duration], [DateTimestamp], [LastSuccessDateTimestamp])
            VALUES (s.[Database], s.Mode, s.[Status], s.Duration, s.DateTimestamp, NULL);';

EXEC (@SQL, @Database, @Passed, @Duration) AT EHRCLSQL01;
```

Comment: That's along the lines I was thinking, since you not really merging from a record set on the local server--you just "merging" on set of values.